# Error while Add Columns to a Hive table from Pyspark code

Tags: hadoop, hive, pyspark

I have a table in Hive and I am running a pyspark code to add a column to that hive table. This is the command i'm executing

`ALTER TABLE db_name.mytable ADD COLUMNS (column1 string)`

But I am only running into this error message :

```
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o61.sql.
    : java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed

at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.CatalogTable.partitionSchema(interface.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$alterTableSchema$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:662)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$alterTableSchema$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:646)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$alterTableSchema$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:646)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.alterTableSchema(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:646)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.alterTableSchema(SessionCatalog.scala:372)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.AlterTableAddColumnsCommand.run(tables.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:623)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Where am I going wrong here ? Any help would be really useful. Thanks.

Comment: Which `spark` version are you using?

Comment: something like spark 2.x

Comment: Can you try creating the table through `sqlContext`? And then run `Alter` on it.

Comment: `from pyspark.sql import HiveContext 
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)`